# Jest: How to test a component that dispatch an API action

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new to testing,
I am trying to understand if it's possible to test an API call that dispatch from the component.
Is it possible to wait for a response from the server?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup, waitForElement } from 'react-testing-library';
import 'jest-dom/extend-expect'

import App from 'src/app';

import { store } from 'stories/index.stories.js';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

const renderComponent = () => (<App />);

it('renders correctly', () => {

  const { container, getByText, queryAllByText, getByPlaceholderText } = renderComponent();

  expect(container).not.toBeEmpty();

  expect(getByText(/Discover/i)).toBeTruthy();

  const discoverBtn = getByText(/Discover/i);

  fireEvent.click(discoverBtn); // this will dispatch an action from the component

  //what should i do next ?
});
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far? It's far to help you with this little information

Comment: I'v edit the question

Comment: It depends on what is supposed to happen when you click on the button

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it.

First I put all my `fetch` requests in a separate file, say `/api/index.js`. In this way I can easily mock them in my tests.

Then I perform the actions that a user would do. Finally I check that the API got called and that the DOM was updated correctly.

```
import { aFetchMethod } from './api'

// With jest.mock our API method does nothing
// we don't want to hit the server in our tests
jest.mock('./api')

it('renders correctly', async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />)

  aFetchMethod.mockResolvedValueOnce('some data that makes sense for you')
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Discover'))

  expect(aFetchMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  expect(aFetchMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith('whatever you call it with')

  // Let's assume you now render the returned data
  await wait(() => getByText('some data that makes sense for you'))
})
```